# How to change the color of an individual item of the plot chart in Flex?

Tags: web, flex4.5

I am creating a plot chart in Flex that takes in an array collection. The array collection has the following format:

```
var provinces:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection (
{PROVINCE:"Ha Noi", Male:50000, Female:20000},
{PROVINCE:"Ha Tay", Male:100000, Female:10000},
{PROVINCE:"Quang Ninh", Male:75250, Female:45021},
{PROVINCE:"Hai Phong", Male:10000, Female:25000});
```

I want to use different colors to display different provinces on the plot chart. Moreover, I want to create a legend for different provinces. Would anyone know how to do it? Some code example would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: In my opinion [ColumnChart](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=charts_types_10.html) is more informative to your data, Try ColumnChart instead of Plot Char and if PlotChart is your only case then i think you need to write your own Custom PlotChart with all your specifications